# cURL request refusing to connect on Flask server

Tags: python, curl, flask, get

I have a simple Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():  
    return 'Hello World!'
```

When I run `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/` on the command line, I get the error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What command are you running for your flask server?

Comment: Are you running this on Docker?

Comment: Are you running this script? I can't see any `app.run()` line in your code above.

Comment: I'm running ```app.run(debug=True)```

Comment: Not using docker.

Answer (score 1):

If the code snippet above is exactly the same to your code that you are trying to run then you are missing `app.run()` statement: Also You can specify any port number with `port=<port_number>` parameter in `app.run()`

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():  
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and then run this script

Comment: try running on a different port, by passing `port=5500` params in `app.run(debug=True, port=5500)` and then `curl http://127.0.0.1:5500`